# What is the object and verb of this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Medical reports indicate that the murder was committed with     a sharp instrument.
My question:
1/ Where is the object of this sentence?
2/ Why we say ( was committed) as a verb and not say (committed) only?

Comment: "was committed" is passive voice (indicated by the presence of the auxiliary verb *was* with the past participle form *committed*) Passive clauses have no object. We can transpose the clause to the active voice by saying, "X committed the murder," where "murder" is now the object. But suppose we don't know who X is. That's one reason to use the passive.

Comment: "The murder" didn't commit anything, it _was committed_.